# Auto spy-ads load on our website page load

Tags: wordpress, ads, google-ads-api

Today, our google ads rejected due to macilious software issue. we have investgated this problem in details.
we have checked the follow at our end:

- we have check thorughly all website code
- we have already scan our website using "malware scanner"
- we have checked the website maleware scanner for virus total.
- we have checked our database
- the time-stamp of all pages are not change in recent time

BUT!
occasionally a pop-up appears at the bottom of the webpage. the screenshot is attached to this message.
[https://exactautoglass.ca/[![enter](https://exactautoglass.ca/%5B!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86TgZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86TgZ.png)

i have tried eveything to run my google ads but it always rejected due to the "Malicious Software". I am looking for the solution!!

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the popup is appearing on your webpage, then you didn't find the malicious code someone has placed (if it was even there, as I looked at your page and didn't find anything).

Remember that malicious code can also be placed in the header of your html file (If attacker got access to your server).

It can also be the result of an **XSS vulnerability**, which is a more likely behavior.

I couldn't replicate the bug on your website, so I can't give further info. I can only relay on your images.